# Why is it okay to swap the integral with the average here?

Tags: integration, convex-analysis, average, convex-geometry

In [these](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf) notes, Pg. 23, they show: $$\text{avg}_U \left(\int_{S^{n-1}} \frac{1}{\|U\theta\|^n_K\|\theta\|^n_K} d\sigma(\theta) \right) = R^{2n}$$

Here's the complete argument, and the line marked $(\star\star\star)$ is the one that I'm talking about:

> The **group of orthogonal transformations** carries an invariant probability measure. This means that we can **average** a function over the group in a natural way. In particular, if $f$ is a function on the sphere and $θ$ is some point on the sphere, the average over orthogonal $U$ of the value $f(Uθ)$ is just the average of $f$ on the sphere: averaging over $U$ *mimics* averaging over the sphere:
> $$\text{avg}_U f(Uθ) = \int_{S^{n-1}}f (\phi) dσ(\phi)$$
> Hence,
> \begin{align*}
>     \text{avg}_U \left(\int_{S^{n-1}} \frac{1}{\|{U\theta}\|^n_K\|{\theta\|}^n_K} d\sigma(\theta) \right) &= \int_{S^{n-1}} \left( \text{avg}_U\frac{1}{\|{U\theta}\|^n_K} \right)\frac{1}{\|{\theta}\|^n_K}d\sigma(\theta)\ (\star\star\star)\\
>     &= \int_{S^{n-1}} \left( \int_{S^{n-1}} \frac{1}{\|{\phi}\|^n_K} d\sigma(\phi) \right)\frac{1}{\|{\theta}\|^n_K}d\sigma(\theta) \\
>     &= \left(\int_{S^{n-1}}\frac{1}{\|{\theta}\|^n_K}d\sigma(\theta)\right)^2 = R^{2n}
> \end{align*}

How did they take the **average inside the integral**? Is that a mistake? If not, why? **Can we always swap averages and integrals like this?**

I'd appreciate any help with understanding the above work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An average is an integral, so Fubini-Tonelli would be the most applicable theorem. In this case, the integrand is non-negative, so we can interchange the order of integration.